# SVG Mask Path is cropped

Tags: javascript, css, svg

I am trying to build a javascript experiment of a dynamic chain which follows the mouse cursor.

Therefore I am useing a SVG wwith the following path:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 300 240">
  <defs>
    <path id="a" d="M143 158q-31-139 9-99" fill="none" stroke-linecap="round"/>
    <mask id="b">
      <rect x="0%" y="0%" width="100%" height="100%" fill="#fff"/>
      <use href="#a" stroke-width="4" stroke-dasharray="6 14" stroke-dashoffset="7" stroke="#000"/>
    </mask>
  </defs>
  <use href="#a" stroke-width="8" stroke-dasharray="6 14" stroke-dashoffset="7" stroke="#333" stroke-opacity=".8" mask="url(#b)"/>
  <use href="#a" stroke-width="2" stroke-dasharray="12 8" stroke="#333" stroke-opacity=".8"/>
</svg>
```

Unfortunately the chain is cropped:

[image: SVG Chain with crop]

Why is this happening?

You can see the [full experiment here](https://codesandbox.io/s/vigorous-maxwell-2z3xfc?file=/src/MouseChain.tsx) (desktop only).

[image: Animated Preview of the problem]

Comment: You don't have to link to an external CodesandBox; add an [Minimal minimal-reproducible-example StackOverflow Snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to your post. It will help readers execute your code with one click. And help create answers with one click. See [How to add a StackOverflow snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269753/feedback-requested-runnable-code-snippets-in-questions-and-answers)

Comment: @RobertLongson - I might be wrong but I believe that's not the reason as i can draw elements further left of the chain.

Comment: The coordinates of a point on any svg path is centred across the width of the line. You have to allow for half the line thickness extra when calculating boundaries.

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman - thanks now the SVG can be expected right in the snippet preview :) 
I'll keep the linked example to show why I want to use the svg that way

Comment: @DavePritlove how can I do that?

Comment: I believe the problem is somehow in the mask element but I don't understand why

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Long story short: A `mask` works within an object's *bounding box*, but the bounding box of any element doesn't include the stroke width.

Therefore, the default `mask` adds 10% padding around the bounding box with its [`x`, `y`, `width`, `height` and `maskUnits` attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/mask#attributes). This works in most cases, but fails when an element is slim and almost horizontal or vertical.

See the below image: The blue rectangle is your path's bounding box, and the green is the area where the `mask` does its job. You can see that some of the path sticks out to the left and right.

[image: SVG mask area]

So you must change the `mask` attributes to work for you. For example, make it cover the whole image:

```
<mask id="b" maskUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%">
```

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by adding `maskUnits="userSpaceOnUse"`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/maskUnits

(changed the viewBox to better display it in an SO snippet)

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 40 300 240">
  <defs>
    <path id="a" d="M143 158q-31-139 9-99" fill="none" stroke-linecap="round"/>
    <mask id="b"  maskUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <rect x="0%" y="0%" width="100%" height="100%" fill="#fff"/>
      <use href="#a" stroke-width="4" stroke-dasharray="6 14" stroke-dashoffset="7" stroke="#000"/>
    </mask>
  </defs>
  <use href="#a" stroke-width="8" stroke-dasharray="6 14" stroke-dashoffset="7" stroke="#333" stroke-opacity=".8" mask="url(#b)"/>
  <use href="#a" stroke-width="2" stroke-dasharray="12 8" stroke="#333" stroke-opacity=".8"/>
</svg>
```